# Failures : Service worker does not successfully serve the manifest's start_url

Tags: service-worker

I'm creating PWA for my website and this error message has consumed a lot of time of me. I will appreciate any help provided on this.

Using React-redux + webpack + babel + OfflinePlugin

sw.js is generated in build folder

main..js ( build folder) container registry script.

My Manifest.json below :

{
  "name": "Test",
  "short_name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon_48x48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 1.0
    },
    {
      "src": "favicon_96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 2.0
    },
    {
      "src": "favicon_144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 3.0
    },
    {
      "src": "favicon_192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 4.0
    },
    {
      "src": "favicon_192x192.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": 4.0
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#317EFB",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "orientation": "any"
}

Check out below images of my directory structure : 
[Directory structure - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD1ls.png)

[Directory structure - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFLiT.png)

Please also find google lighhouse audit report image : [Lighthouse Audit report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dGOR.png)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any answers on this? We need a good definitive answer for this. It's super annoying/frustrating!

Comment: Seems all criteria are met: https://infrequently.org/2016/09/what-exactly-makes-something-a-progressive-web-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with UglifyJS. Service worker was not able to load in cache.. Have resolved it manually.

change
serviceWorkerLoader: `<script>${loadMinified(path.join(__dirname, './service-worker-prod.js'), 'utf-8')}</script>`
to
serviceWorkerLoader: `<script>${loadMinified(path.join(__dirname, './service-worker-prod.js'))}</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this issue when my manifest file wasn't getting cached by the service worker. Lighthouse runs the test offline, and if the manifest file isn't cached, it naturally can't read the start_url.

I'd look at your service worker file and make sure your `manifest.json` or `manifest.webmanifest` is being added to the cache.